# Same model hardwood doesn’t quite match?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, engineered-flooring

We just moved into a house a couple weeks ago. The house previously had hardwood only through the hall/entryway. We got the previous owners to send us the receipt with exactly which model floor was used with which company, so we could extend the hardwood to more rooms.

We used the same company with the same model hardwood, but the new hardwood looks slightly more matte/dull than the previous hardwood installed in March 2021.

Is there anything I can do or apply to the new hardwood to make it match better? The owner of the store we used assured me it was the exact same model. He even went back to his supplier after he’d already delivered the first batch and returned for a batch that was older (closer to the same age as previous hardwood).

[image]

Comment: Most design stuff that comes in pieces/lots, a company will ask you to purchase enough of the same lot to finish job, plus a little over.  Finishes are slightly different for each lot of product, sometimes in same lot.  Did older floor have any varnish/top coat applied to it?  it looks like it have had something applied to it, that new flooring does not have.

Comment: That is a disappointment.   However it is not awful. Over time you will not find it as noticeable.

Comment: I have to wonder if the older floor has been polished/waxed or had some sort of sealer (possibly not described as such - various floor products exist - i.e. "mop and glo" which is really some sort of acrylic coating AFAICT) applied to it in the name of "cleaning" or prepping the house for sale. I expect it will wear in closer over time.

Comment: Are you sure you got the same finish/sheen on the new floors as was on the old?  You can notice the difference between gloss/satin/matte, etc, especially when they're side by side.

Comment: The new batch is probably from a different tree. Same type of tree, just a different tree.